# scroll horizontal and vertically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm following this [Scrolling page](http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery)

I've done with the horizontally.

But I have a question, is it possible to use both (verticall and horizontall) in the same page?

For example, I have 3 items 1,2,3 which scrolling horizontally. Inside the 1, I have another 2 items, (1 will be the 1', and 2', 3'). Can I use the scroll vertically here by using above link?

Comment: dude you did something very wrong while typing links in your question, try again!

Comment: I've forgot the link. http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery

Comment: well fix your answer dont type it here its messy!

Comment: Sorry, i've edited the question.

Comment: You should be able yes, if you would like me to have a go please provide a fiddle with what you have already

Comment: Please take a look at here: http://demo.beta24h.com/1/portfolio/

......I need to add 2 more sections in the third page (the page with fancybox)...Thank you for your help....

Comment: Can't change your code so I cant fiddle around.. Don't think I have time for such a task anw, a tip for your website though, it took me about a !minute! just to load. When clicking on anything on your fancybox again it takes ages to load. You need to do something about that. Good Luck!

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm not good at coding. Just collect plug in and put it in my site. I'm sorry. It's my bad. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/).

It allows you to scroll vertically and horizontally.